# SQL - How to make a list of ints from a column

Tags: sql, list

I have a column named `intColumn` which contains values `valA`, `valB`, ... , `valN`.

I need a simple way to refer to a list of these values to pass into an `IN()` statement.

Perhaps this could be stored in a variable, such as `intList = valA, valB, ... , valN`, where the result would appear as `IN(intList)`.

The motivation for this to avoid hardcoding about 400 values in the `IN()` statement.

What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: If you only want to select things that contain those values, just do a `JOIN` to the table on that column.

Comment: If I understand the request, a sub-query is what you want. `where someValue in (select intColumn from table)`

Comment: Can you please tag RDBMS?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I wouldn't even do an `IN` if you have that many values.  It's easier to do either a `JOIN` or a `WHERE EXISTS`:

`JOIN` method:

```
Select    A.*
From      TableA  A
Join      TableB  B  On  A.SomeColumn = B.IntColumn
```

`EXISTS` method:

```
Select    *
From      TableA  A
Where Exists
(
    Select    *
    From      TableB  B
    Where     A.SomeColumn = B.IntColumn
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
  From SomeTable 
  Where ID in (Select IDs from SomeOtherTable Where SomeCondtion=True)
```